# D3.js, force-graph, cannot display text/label of nodes

Tags: graph, d3.js, data-visualization, label, force-layout

I cannot display labels of nodes using a force-layout in d3.js.

I'm trying with this example http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js

I updated that code only adding zoom, like this:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height).append('svg:g').call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw));

function redraw() {
    console.log("here", d3.event.translate, d3.event.scale);
    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    node.attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
}
```

Why are labels not displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to separately add the text:

```
node.append("text")
    .attr("dx", ".10em")
    .attr("dy", ".10em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

see these examples:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2706022

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292

Comment: For the life of me I can't get these labels to appear.  I started with the example here http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4600693 which already does tooltips but not working. Is there an additional step to tell d3 that the text attribute should be rendered?

Comment: Pay attention not to append text element inside circle. If you copy paste from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2706022 (with labels) and https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045 (no labels) there are little differences.
Text **svg** and **circle** svg goes appended to a group **g** element.